# How to get the actual mean absolute error in cross validation after transforming the target variable y?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, data-transformation, back-transformation

For a target variable `y`, it is transformed using `np.log1p`. Then a random forest regression model is trained using the transformed `y`.

Then I tried to use `cross_val_score` in `sklearn` to compute the `neg_mean_absolute_error`. The mean of the returned scores is `-0.17`. Should I convert it back by using `np.emp1(0.17)`?

But the error is too small. As I am predicting housing price. The error should be much larger than this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should first back-transform the results of the regression and then calculate both the price errors and their absolute mean.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than transforming the estimate of the generalization error, you're better off using a model which transforms the training data and then is capable of predicting back on the original scale.

This is done with `sklearn.compose.TransformTargetRegressor` as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

N = 1000
x = np.random.normal(size = (N, 1))
y = 10 + x + np.random.normal(size = (N, 1))
y = y.ravel()

model = Pipeline([
    ('ttr', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=LinearRegression(), func = np.log1p, inverse_func = lambda x: np.exp(x)-1))
])


cross_val_score(model, x, y, cv=5, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error').mean()

>>>-0.997... #Depending on the data used.
```

Note that our cross validated error is very close to the true standard deviation of the noise (which is 1 in this case) despite the model mispecification (the true conditional mean is linear whereas the model is exponential)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate the mean absolute error ([MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)) using just very basic functions in Python. If `y` is your target variable and you used your transformed target variable `y_trans` to train the model, you will get a transformed outcome variable `out_trans`. To get a meaningful MAE, in housing price e.g., you would have to transform your outcome variable,`out_trans`, using the inverse transformation function you used in `y`. **Note that this is different from transforming the MAE itself, as you suggested.** After that, the MAE is just the mean of the differences between `y` and `out`, in module:

```py
import numpy as np
mae = np.mean(abs(y) - abs(out))
```

You could of course compute the MAE with the transformed quantities, but as you said, the unit won't be that meaningful.

Comment: Thank you! By using your method, I can compute the `MAE` for the trained model. But what if I want to compute the average `MAE` in cross validation? Can I do that in `cross_val_score`? Or I need to use the `pipeline` in `sklearn`